# Saving image to server directory using SpringBoot with Android

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-boot, web

I am developing an application that sends images to the server. I am wanting to save the photos coming from the application in the local server side folder. For this I am using SpriingBoot for API development and on Android I am submitting the request via Json using the Volley library.

I already tried to convert the string that came in the request to byte [] and then save it to an Image.io format file, but it is not possible to save the image. Can someone help me save the image to the local server directory?

Code android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.8:8080/api/paciente";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "foto";
String foto = "null";
public static final String TAG = "LOG";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);


    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            registerForms();

        }
    });
}

public void tirarFoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            foto = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto anexada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void registerForms() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.contains("Erro")) {
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Erro ao enviar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Lat: " + "Caiu aqui");
            } else {
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "String: " + foto);
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_IMAGE, foto);
            Log.i(TAG, "Lat: " + map);
            return map;

        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Code API:

Service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paciente", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/json" })
public @ResponseBody Paciente cadastraPaciente(@Valid Paciente paciente) throws Exception {
    byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(foto.getBytes());
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/carlo/Downloads/SisCAF/images/myImage1.png");
         fos.write(imgBytes);
         FileDescriptor fd = fos.getFD();
         fos.flush();
         fd.sync();
         fos.close(); 
     }


    return paciente;
}
```

As it is in the code, returns that the image attribute is null

Comment: assuming the `BufferedImage` is correctly read, try mentioning your `path` with the `relative` one, like so: `"./out.jpg"`, does it work?

Comment: @Phill the problem is converting ByteArrayInputStream to ByteArrayInputStream because it returns a null image

Comment: you mean `bis` is null right?

Comment: Phill, yes, is null

Comment: okay what about `byte[ ] encoded`?

Comment: it returns the byte array normally. The problem is in the Conversion ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream (encoded);

Comment: alright, and why do you encode it with base64? is it necessary?

Comment: I was converting to base 64 and then converting to Image.Io, but if I can convert straight from String (Json) to Image.io. As I don't know much about image conversion, I am seeing possibilities.

Comment: what happens if you remove the encoding?

Comment: Commenting out the line and converting the direct byte array to Image.IO reads as follows: The method read (File) in the type ImageIO is not applicable for the arguments (byte [])

Comment: try this if possbile: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded));
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("./out.jpg"));`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using @noname's backend implementation you can easily send images to your server using **Retrofit** in a nice and clean way:

add to build file:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Configure Retrofit inside your app like this:

```
public class NetworkClient {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
private static Retrofit retrofit;
public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

define you API calls sing simple interfaces:

```
public interface UploadAPIs {
@Multipart
@POST("/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("name") RequestBody requestBody);
```

}

finally, send your images using the above configuration like this:

```
private void uploadToServer(String filePath) {
 Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(this);
 UploadAPIs uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(UploadAPIs.class);
 //Create a file object using file path
 File file = new File(filePath);
 // Create a request body with file and image media type
 RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
 // Create MultipartBody.Part using file request-body,file name and part name 
 MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
 //Create request body with text description and text media type
 RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "image-type");
 // 
 Call call = uploadAPIs.uploadImage(part, description);
 call.enqueue(new Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
     }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
     }
 });
```

}

Answer (score 2):

this is method which I am using in spring app in my PictureManager class :

```java
public static void storeFile(MultipartFile[] files) {
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
      String[] fileNamePieces = file.getOriginalFilename().split("_");

      File picture = new File("\\\\IP-SERVER\\folder\\stored\\Photos\\" + fileNamePieces[0] + "\\");
      String productId = getProductId(fileNamePieces[0], LABEL_TYPE.valueOf(fileNamePieces[1]).getLableType());

      if (!picture.exists())
        picture.mkdirs();
      try {
        copyFileToLocation(file, "\\\\IP-SERVER\\folder\\Quality stored\\Photos\\Arch\\" + productId.trim() + ".jpg");
        copyFileToLocation(file, picture + "\\" + file.getOriginalFilename());
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

which I am mapping in main RestController like:

```java
@PostMapping("/file")
  public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
    PictureManager.storeFile(files);
  }
```

And in here you have method which I implemented in android also I am setting up URL to http where my spring method is mapped, so for example: http://spring-app:8080/storeFile
That method need to be set as POST method.

```java
public void sendFile(final File [] files){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
          httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);
          httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
          httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
          httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
          httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=****");
          BufferedOutputStream dos = new BufferedOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

          dos.write("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=****\r\n".getBytes());
          dos.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n".getBytes());
          for (File file : files) {
//            if(file.length() <= 0)
//              continue;

            BufferedInputStream fileInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile()));

            String what_is_here = String.format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", file.getName());
            dos.write("--****\r\n".getBytes());
            dos.write(what_is_here.getBytes());
            dos.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            dos.flush();
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
              b[i] = (byte) fileInput.read();
            }

            Log.wtf("BYUTE", b.length + "");
            dos.write(b);
            dos.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            dos.flush();
            fileInput.close();
          }
          dos.write("--*****--\r\n".getBytes());
          dos.flush();
          dos.close();
          Log.wtf("STATUS", httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() + "");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }
```